# Android: textView is added dynamicly. How to add this to specific line

Tags: android, background, textview, line, stretched

I have 5 textViews which are added dinamicly but each textViews covers others. How to add each textView to specific line?

```
for(int z=0;z<c;z++){
    TextView lastHour = new TextView(projectActivity.this);
    lastHour.setPadding(5,z*35,0,0); // it currently allows me to see each textView in other line
    lastHour.setText("text"+z);                 
    relative_layout_for_last.addView(lastHour);
}
```

When I use setPadding, background for textView is stretched.
I just want to add each textView in other line than previous textViews.

Comment: maybe the background of the layout that contain the textviews is streched, not the textviews background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding won't do what you want. It will just increase the space between the top and the content. Either add them to a LinearLayout with vertical orientation, like Bram said, or if you're willing to keep your RelativeLayout, add a layout_below constraint specifying the id of your view on top.

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             50, (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lp.leftMargin=5;
or(int z=0;z<c;z++){
    TextView lastHour = new TextView(projectActivity.this);
    lastHour.setPadding(5,z*35,0,0); // it currently allows me to see each textView in other line
    lastHour.setText("text"+z);    
    lastHour.setLayoutParams(lp);             
    relative_layout_for_last.addView(lastHour);
}
```

like this you can add own layout parameter as like you did in XML and set the text view approximately in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap them in a linear layout and set the orientation to vertical.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

If you need any code snippets, please ask. I am in a bit of a hurry here;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `LinearLayout` to surround your `TextViews`. The orientation of the layout should be `vertical`.

If you need to stick with the `RelativeLayout` you should add this:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, theTextViewAbove.getId());
```